# Liquibase maven multimodule

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, liquibase

I'm trying to get liquibase to generate changesets based on Hibernate entities.
We have a multi-module maven project, with persisted objects sprinkled around the different modules.
When I run mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog, it executes for every module, repeating same output over and over in the generated changelog file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution to this:
so we have a bunch of core maven modules and a set of modules with customizations for specific customers.
Ultimately the customer modules are "top level" modules, and when application is packaged, it's packaged for the specific top-level customer module.

So solution was to add the following to all but the "top level" customer modules

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

my advise is to managed db schema out of your exiting maven modules, in a separate one:

1. if these modules are linked to the same database, you have no choice ti have a unique schema, and a unique liquibase management
2. if these modules use different schema, you can have different liquibase changelog. The generation will be different because of different schema

Eric

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option. Each maven module is responsible for a different business logic module, which "owns" the tables associated with entities inside the module